# Can I use solr cloud replica for reindexing

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I need to change types in my SolrCloud, consequently, I need to do reindexing. Can I add new replica and then change types and then delete my initial replica and use collection with new types. Or maybe you know more "right" way of reindexing and you can suggest it to me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DIH to import documents from one core to another: http://www.od-bits.com/2018/07/reindexing-solr-core.html

HTH,
Emir